# How to combine thread and threadlocal in java

Tags: java

I have some methods that is declared as below:

This class is declared to use `ThreadLocal` for getting `Service` component from container.

```
public class ThreadContext {
    private Connector connector;
    private static ThreadLocal threadLocal = new ThreadLocal() {        
        @Override
        protected Connector initialValue() {
            Service service =  
                   (Service) Container.getComponentInstanceOfType(Service.class);
            Connector connector = service.getConnector();  
            return connector;
        }
    };

    public static Connector get() {
        return Connector threadLocal.get();
    }
}
```

The `Connector` is middle class

```
public class Connector {
    public Collection<Result> search() {
        User user = ConversationUser.getCurrent()
    }
}
```

The `ConversationUser` is declared to use `ThreadLocal` also

```
public class ConversationUser {
    private static ThreadLocal<ConversationUser> current = 
                                            new ThreadLocal<ConversationUser>();

    public static ConversationUser getCurrent() {
        return current.get();//(1)
    }
}
```

Then, i write a thread to do something as below:

```
Thread thread = null;
thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
        ThreadContext context = new ThreadContext();          
        Collection<Result> result = context.get().search();//(2)
        resultsTemp.put("File", result);
    }
});          
thread.start();
```

This thread works normally but happens `NullPointerException` at line (2).
As i investigated the method gets return null at line (1).

It is really confused to me. I don't understand why the problem happens. Please give me some clarifications for this, thanks.

Comment: I tried to answer your question but I found it too confusing. There are multiple compilation errors in your example, and it seems incomplete. The order of execution seems different from what you describe, since `search` calls `getCurrent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some testing and the problem is because of the private static `ThreadLocal` variable, I dont know why but this is not linking the object to the `ThreadLocal`, it seems that the object is not being created. I would need some more time to investigate it.

Anyway I see two solutions for you to fix this problem:

1. Create this class as a Singleton

   ```
   public class ConversationUser extends ThreadLocal<ConversationUser>{
       private static ThreadLocal<ConversationUser> current= null;

   @Override
       protected ConversationUser initialValue() {
           return new ConversationUser();
       }

       public static ConversationUser getCurrent() {
           if (current == null) {
               current = new ConversationUser();
           }
           return current.get();
       }

       }
   ```

   //usage `ConversationUser.getCurrent()`
2. Forget about this static variable and always access it by creating a new instance of the `ThreadLocal` object

   ```
   public class ConversationUser extends ThreadLocal<ConversationUser>{

   @Override
       protected ConversationUser initialValue() {
           return new ConversationUser();
       }

       }
   ```

   //usage `new ConversationUser().get();`

Answer (score 4):

You are initializing `ConversationUser.current` to `new ThreadLocal<ConversationUser>()` without extending it anonymously to override `initialValue()`, like you do for `ThreadContext.threadLocal`. Because of this, there is nothing to tell it how to populate itself when `get` is first called. Since there is no code calling `set` to populate it manually, `get` returns `null`.

See the [`ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) javadocs for more information and a helpful example.

Comment: I guess I'll just undelete this since people are repeating me.

Comment: @fmodos Yeah, that was fault for briefly deleting it when I had doubts about the question. But it seems like useful info even if the question isn't totally clear. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: no problem, anyway this is the correct answer... he never set an instance the the ThreadLocal

Comment: Firstly, i guess this issue comes from a thread and a threadlocal. I thought about the solution is to use synchronized for method get. But it seem is not ok.

However, current variable is initialized already in somewhere in Container. The evidence is if i use http request to call properly it  work well, no exception happens but not thread.

Comment: @fmodos Do you get my problem?

Comment: @phamcanh I did some testing and besides the problems listed by Paul Bellora, there was another problem with the way you were accessing the object, I posted an answer with info about it.